# AngularJS : ng-model doesn't update correctly with ng-keydown. ng-model off by one character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am looking at text input on AngularJS as it changes by the user.

However, it seems that when I print to the console from my .js, the ng-model is off by one character because there seems to be a lag with the update by one keydown.

For example:
If the user types "hello" I see "hell" until another keydown is triggered, which will then update what I see to "hello" but the user input could be "helloW"

If that makes sense... Sorry.

Basically, is there a way that I can force update my ng-model from my controller so that I can see the user input as it comes in with each keydown?

I cannot post my code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using "**ng-keyup**" with "**ng-model**"  instead of **ng-keydown** :)

Here the doc: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

```js
 var app = angular.module('app',[]);
 app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {      
    $scope.onKeyUpPrint = function(){
      // You can name the function as you want
      // scope will be triggered exactly on key Up
      console.log($scope.inputModel);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
<h1>Use ng-keyup<h1>
<input type="text" name="inputbox" ng-keyup="onKeyUpPrint()" ng-model="inputModel">
</body>
```

Comment: Keyup worked perfectly for me. Just had to change keydown to keyup

Answer (score 2):

Use **`ng-change`**  with **`ng-model`**

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);
 myApp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {      
    $scope.print = function(){
      console.log($scope.myname);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
<input type="text" name="inputbox" ng-change="print()" ng-model="myname">
</body>
```